# TV connected to PC via HDMI. Will it slow down?

Tags: hdmi, desktop-computer, tv

If the TV is connected via HDMI to the computer but turned off, will it overload my computer and slow it down? Should i disconnect it from pc?

Comment: Try it and see what happens. You won't break anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitor is off but still detected by computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1380728/monitor-is-off-but-still-detected-by-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, if you have your computer's HDMI connected to the tv when it is off, the computer might think you have a screen available there and might extend your desktop to it.   This could be confusing as your mouse would not be visible when it is on the powered off display.

However, your computer may also detect that the TV is off and decide to ignore it as if it was unplugged.  If your computer supports CEC, it may even be able to turn the tv on, typically when the computer is turned on.