# Windows 11: How to prevent mouse cursor going off screen to other, switched off monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, mouse-cursor

I have 4 monitors connected to my Windows 11 system. But I don't always use them. Most of the time I just use one monitor and the other 3 are switched off. However, each time I move my mouse too far to the right (or left), the mouse cursor disappears and is apparently "visible" on a screen that is switched off.

Is there any way to prevent that? So the mouse cursor can only move between monitors that are actually switched on?

Comment: have you tried this - it's for w10 but may be relevant https://superuser.com/questions/1380728/monitor-is-off-but-still-detected-by-computer

Comment: It helps - kinda. If I set my monitor to "PC Screen Only" (using Windows+P keys), then the mouse no longer travels of the screen, but for some reason when I play games, my frame rates drop by 60%. Setting it to "Extend" and my frame rates return to normal.

Comment: if the monitor is powered off at the socket, does the mouse still travel to the screen area?